# Building database relationship: a product compatible with another product

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, relationship

I'm building a database with Ruby on Rails which basically store products.
One of my main concern is that in the future, I want to be able to know the compatibility which two products.

I don't know how to build that in "a Rails way". First I was thinking about creating a new table `Compatibility` with the two `product_id` but I guess there is one more elegant solution ?

Comment: Is it adequate to say that product X *is compatible* with product Y? If that's the case, and any two products could *potentially* be compatible, then a `Compatibility` table is what you need and there's not a more elegant way to do it as long as you are using the canonical ActiveRecord means of defining `Compatibility`.

Comment: Yes @lurker it is what I want. Product X **is compatible with** Product Y.

Comment: Then the link @ArslanAli has provided will give you the "Rails way" of doing this. Internally, it will use the table you need that establishes the relationship (in the link, the `Friendship` model would be analogous to your `Compatibility` model).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Self-Referential Association**](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association) is the solution. A product is compatible with another product, so the relationship is between two *same* items.

Second thing, this is the inverse relationship as well. If a product A is compatible with product B, then product B is also compatible with product A. The railscasts mentioned in the link clearly explains this thing.

Comment: It's exactly what I was looking for. I should have search for a "frienship" use case example !

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Rails has a magical way of dealing with this kind of complexity.